# Automatically delete rows older than 7 days in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I want to delete rows from the database that are older than 7 days. I went through some questions here on Stack but can't find one that helped at all.

I already found this way to do it:

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE updateDt < (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

And this, to create a event in the database:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT `delete7DayOldMessages`
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2015-09-01 00:00:00'
  ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO BEGIN
   delete from users
   where datediff(now(),updateDt)>6; 
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Is it right to transform these two examples above into this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT `delete7DayOldMessages`
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2015-09-01 00:00:00'
  ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DELETE FROM users WHERE updateDt < (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
DELIMITER ;
```

?

Comment: Have you tried it? Does it work?

Comment: I tried, then I create a row and changed the date for test but it doesnt delete. When I run in the SQL works just fine.

Comment: Maybe the event runs at a specific time, I don't know if I can control it.

Comment: It runs every 24 hours starting at 2015-09-01 00:00:00, i.e. at midnight every day. If you want it to run at a different time, specify the time of day in your STARTS clause. For testing, you might want to change the event to run every minute instead of every day. When you have confirmed that it works, then change the event back to run once per day if you want.

Comment: *Is it right to transform these two examples above into this:* Remove both DELIMITER statements.Add final `;`.

Comment: *I tried, then I create a row and **changed the date** for test but it doesnt delete.* This is incorrect test. Either decrease firing regularity (`ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE`, for example) or wait for tomorrow than look.